# value disapears when trying to get it back on second Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I opening **Fragment B** from **Fragment A** with **startActivityForResult** when **Fragment B** closes I get String value from **EditText** to **Fragment A** and everything works fine but now I opening same **Fragment B** from **Fragment A** and I want it to have that earlier returned value but it disappears

here I'm storing **purposeText** value from **editText** but not saving to json yet I want it to be saved on exiting **Fragment A**

```
    public class Cloud {


    private static final String JSON_ID = "id";
    private static final String JSON_PURPOSE = "purpose";

    private UUID mId;
    private String purposeText = "";



    public Cloud() {

        mId = UUID.randomUUID();
    }



    public Cloud(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
        mId = UUID.fromString(json.getString(JSON_ID));
        if (json.has(JSON_PURPOSE)){
            purposeText = json.getString(JSON_PURPOSE);
        }

    }

    public JSONObject toJSON() throws JSONException{

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put(JSON_ID, mId.toString());
        json.put(JSON_PURPOSE, purposeText);

        return json;
    }


    @Override
    //Using get and set methods to get it in private String
    public String getPurposeText(){return purposeText;}
    public void setPurposeText(String purpose){purposeText = purpose;}



    public UUID getId() {return mId;};

}
```

In **Fragment A** I'm getting text and setting it to **textview** and it works, then setting it back to setter in **Cloud class**

```
    public class AddFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "Cload";
    public static final String EXTRA_DREAM_ID = "com.example.tadas.dreamcload1.dream_id";
    private static final  int REQUEST_DATE = 0;
    private static final int REQUEST_TEXT =1;

    private Cloud dCloud;
    private TextView purposeView;
    private String comeBackPurpose;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        dCloud = new Cloud();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        getActivity().setTitle("Add new dream");

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add,parent,false);

        purposeView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.dream_purpose);
        purposeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),DreamPurposeActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_TEXT);
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TEXT){

            comeBackPurpose = data.getStringExtra("comeBackPurpose");
           // Log.e(TAG,"SHITFACE " + comeBackPurpose);
            purposeView.setText(comeBackPurpose);
            dCloud.setPurposeText(comeBackPurpose);
            Log.e(TAG,"SHITFACE " + dCloud.getPurposeText());
        }
    }


    public static AddFragment newInstance(UUID dreamId) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(EXTRA_DREAM_ID, dreamId);

        AddFragment fragment = new AddFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return  fragment;
    }
}
```

Now In **Fragment B** I'm trying to set that text back to **EditText** in **onCreateView** method but it gets default value, what should I do to fix that?

```
    public class PurposeFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String EXTRA_D = "com.dropstudio.drea.dr_ids";
    private static final String TAG = "Cload";

    private EditText purposeEText;
    private String purposeEditText;
    private Cloud mCloud;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mCloud = new Cloud();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dream_purpose_edit,container,false);
        purposeEText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.purpose_edit);


        purposeEText.setText(mCloud.getPurposeText());

        return v;
    }


    public void savePurpose(){

        purposeEditText = purposeEText.getText().toString();
        mCloud.setPurposeText(purposeEditText);
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("comeBackPurpose",purposeEditText);
        getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
        getActivity().finish();


    }

    public static PurposeFragment newInstance(UUID dreaIds) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(EXTRA_D, dreaIds);

        PurposeFragment fragment = new PurposeFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Fragment B` , you are creating a new `Cloud` object in `onCreate()` and trying to get the value from that object in `onCreateView()` which will always be `null`.

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mCloud = new Cloud(); //New instance will be created
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dream_purpose_edit,container,false);
        purposeEText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.purpose_edit);


        purposeEText.setText(mCloud.getPurposeText()); // 'mCloud' is a new object everytime and hence will not have your saved value

        return v;
    }
```

For your task, either use `SharedPreferences` or pass the saved value while instantiating `Fragment B`.